# why is xcode 7 not running an app on ios 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7-beta4

Lately installed Xcode 7 beta 4.
My app will not run on an iOS 9.0 device, although it will run on an iOS 9.0 simulator, and an iOS 8.4 device (using Xcode 7b4).

Xcode shows "Running %app_name on %device_name", the icon shows up on the device, but does not run, and that's how it stays.

Debug console shows nothing (checked the preferences, also, when using an iOS 8.4 device it shows output log as expected).

Another app that I created runs fine, it's just this app, on iOS9 device (Sim works smoothly).

No exception is thrown, no compilation error... nothing to go on.

Trying to start the app from the phone itself results in a request to send notifications (ok behaviour) and crashes...

Any ideas ?

> EDIT:

In the device console output, I these two messages (not always):

> Aug  4 11:39:53 iOS-9-test-device syslog_relay(liblockdown.dylib)[117]
>   : The connection is now invalid. Aug  4 11:39:53
>   iOS-9-test-device lockbot[79] : got an unknown event

And this is a crash report from the device itself :

```
Incident Identifier: C6A70E35-2ACD-4A17-959C-547DE3CC39F0 CrashReporter Key:   5c34ba5da623fd5860d5d4059ad9f46615e4e3f9 Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1 Process:             MyAppName [6737] Path:      /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/099D6717-A7A5-45A5-96DE-92810AE0476A/MyAppName.app/MyAppName Identifier:          com.MyOrgName.MyAppName Version:             7 (2.2.10) Code Type:           ARM (Native) Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-08-04 11:47:38.38 +0300 Launch Time:         2015-08-04 11:47:23.23 +0300 OS Version:          iOS 9.0 (13A4254v) Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020 Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash) Highlighted by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information: com.MyOrgName.MyAppName failed to scene-create after 14.65s (launch took 0.35s of total time limit
15.00s)

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 3.220 (user 3.220, system 0.000), 11% CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.779, 3% CPU

Filtered syslog: None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35a09b08 __psynch_mutexwait + 24 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9cad0 _pthread_mutex_lock + 412 2  libc++.1.dylib                  0x349bfa60 std::__1::mutex::lock() + 4 3   VectorKit                        0x323165be
-[VKTileSetBackedTileSource setStyleManager:] + 222 4   VectorKit                       0x320db374 -[VKMapModel createSourceForLayer:tileSet:mode:] + 1260 5  VectorKit                         0x320dab7c -[VKMapModel sourceForLayer:mode:] + 228 6   VectorKit                       0x320da52a -[VKMapModel configureTileSources] + 402 7   VectorKit       0x32166234 -[VKMapModel forceMapType:animated:] + 5068 8   VectorKit    0x3216a64a -[VKMapModel initShouldRasterize:mapPurpose:tileGroupIdentifier:locale:contentScale:]
+ 3378 9   VectorKit                        0x32157a74 -[VKMapCanvas initShouldRasterize:contentScale:target:device:inBackground:locale:] + 680 10  VectorKit                       0x320cd1de -[VKMapView initWithGlobe:shouldRasterize:inBackground:] + 846 11  MapKit            0x24e5299a -[MKBasicMapView initWithFrame:andGlobe:shouldRasterize:]
+ 346 12  MapKit                            0x24e821a0 -[MKMapView _commonInitFromIB:gestureRecognizerHostView:showsAttribution:] + 976 13  MapKit                          0x24e82d28 -[MKMapView initWithCoder:] + 124 14  UIKit                          0x27cecd14 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 776 15  UIKit                         0x27cec9fc -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 292 16  UIKit          0x27bf794a -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 110 17  UIKit        0x27cecd14 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 776 18  UIKit             0x27cecca6 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 666 19  UIKit             0x27cec9fc -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 292 20  UIKit          0x27bf6ede -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1106 21  UIKit      0x27ad2396 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 318 22 UIKit                             0x278bd842 -[UIViewController loadView]
+ 138 23  UIKit                             0x27785fb0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 132 24  UIKit                           0x27842a92 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 34 25  UIKit                          0x27842992 -[UINavigationController
_updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 282 26  UIKit                          0x27841d9c -[UINavigationController
_startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 80 27  UIKit                           0x278419f2 -[UINavigationController
_startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 842 28  UIKit                          0x2784163c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 48 29 UIKit                             0x278415b2 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 210 30  UIKit                          0x2778246c
-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 640 31  QuartzCore                     0x27099f64 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 124 32  QuartzCore                      0x27095714 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 348 33  QuartzCore       0x270955a4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
+ 12 34  QuartzCore                     0x27094b0c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 364 35  QuartzCore   0x270947ce CA::Transaction::commit() + 586 36  QuartzCore               0x2708e17a CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 134 37  CoreFoundation                  0x23638a3a
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18 38  CoreFoundation                   0x23636d02 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 278 39  CoreFoundation                  0x23587abc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544 40  CoreFoundation                    0x23587890 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 41  UIKit                           0x277f2a82 -[UIApplication
_run] + 522 42  UIKit                           0x277ed314 UIApplicationMain + 140 43  MyAppName                        0x000bb176 main (main.m:16) 44  libdyld.dylib                   0x3593a9cc start + 0

Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x35a0a92c
__workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9c8c0 _pthread_wqthread + 1032 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35a9c4a4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35a0b3c0 kevent_qos + 24 1   libdispatch.dylib                0x3591ecfa _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 250 2 libdispatch.dylib               0x3591170a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x35a0a92c
__workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9c8c0 _pthread_wqthread + 1032 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35a9c4a4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x35a0a92c
__workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9c8c0 _pthread_wqthread + 1032 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35a9c4a4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x359f60b0 mach_msg_trap + 20 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x359f5eac mach_msg + 36 2   CoreFoundation                 0x23638e34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 132 3   CoreFoundation                  0x2363718e __CFRunLoopRun + 1046 4   CoreFoundation                 0x23587a9c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 512 5   CoreFoundation                    0x23587890 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 6   CFNetwork                       0x22f166ea +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482 7   Foundation                       0x2447eb0e __NSThread__start__ + 1098 8 libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35a9ea84 _pthread_body + 136 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9e9f6 _pthread_start + 106 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35a9c4b0 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  GAIThread Thread 6: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x359f60b0 mach_msg_trap + 20 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x359f5eac mach_msg + 36 2   CoreFoundation                 0x23638e34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 132 3   CoreFoundation          0x2363718e __CFRunLoopRun + 1046 4   CoreFoundation                 0x23587a9c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 512 5   CoreFoundation                0x23587890 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 6   Foundation                      0x243afb44 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 264 7   Foundation                     0x243fe8c0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run]
+ 76 8   MyAppName                      0x0015ccac +[GAI threadMain:] + 60 9   Foundation                       0x2447eb0e __NSThread__start__ + 1098 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x35a9ea84 _pthread_body + 136 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9e9f6 _pthread_start + 106 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35a9c4b0 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  NetworkLoad Thread 7: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x359f60b0 mach_msg_trap + 20 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x359f5eac mach_msg + 36 2   CoreFoundation                 0x23638e34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 132 3   CoreFoundation          0x2363718e __CFRunLoopRun + 1046 4   CoreFoundation                 0x23587a9c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 512 5   CoreFoundation                0x23587890 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 6   GeoServices                     0x2c90c76a _runNetworkThread + 462 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9ea84 _pthread_body + 136 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9e9f6 _pthread_start + 106 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35a9c4b0 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private Thread 8: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35a09fec __select + 20 1   CoreFoundation                 0x2363dd44 __CFSocketManager + 568 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9ea84 _pthread_body + 136 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35a9e9f6 _pthread_start + 106 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35a9c4b0 thread_start + 4
```

> No thread state (register information) available

Comment: "and crashes" And the console log on the phone then says...?

Comment: Yes, please provide the crash log or sample code.  There's not much we can do to help explain the crash without either.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the MKMapView - I think it's just indirectly related to iOS 9 on your device. It's rather because this view seems to corrupt somehow something? Just remove it from the xib/storyboard and try to run the app please.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest Xcode 7 beta 5 and iOS 9 beta 5 just resolved the issue. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I'm seeing Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash) on ios9.0 device (xcode 7.1)